# To search Group in LDAP using search.context

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query, spring-ldap, ldapconnection

How can I search a group(groupOfNames) in LDAP where as an input I can only pass the group name.Names of the groups created are unique.
I am using LDAP eclipse plugin only, to search the group Hierarchy.
I want the JAVA Code to search the group through it's cn(common name) which will be unique.

e.g.,

```
void searchGroupName("sampleGroup")
{
context.search(String groupRoot,String sampleGroup,SearchControls ctls);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you will be using Spring LDAP, since the question is tagged with that. Using Spring LDAP 2.x you would do something along the lines of:

```
Group group = ldapTemplate.searchForObject(
                query().base(groupRoot).where("cn").is(sampleGroup),
                new AbstractContextMapper<Group>({
                  protected Group doMapFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx) {
                    // Build Group instance here using ctx.getStringAttribute()
                    return Group;
                  }
                });
```

Or, if you're using Spring LDAP ODM and have annotated your Group domain class appropriately (see the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/#odm) for details on that):

```
Group group = ldapTemplate.findOne(
                 query().where("cn").is(sampleGroup), 
                 Group.class);
```

For a complete application example working with users and groups, check out the [Spring LDAP user admin sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/tree/master/samples/user-admin).